# Como utilizar ArrayList en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, arraylist

Necesito utilizar un `ArrayList` en JavaScript para manipular dato y pasarlos por ajax.

**Por ejemplo:** Establecer que tipo de transporte es, marca, año y color.

por ejemplo var datos = {"Automovil", "Nissan", "2010", "Rojo"}

**Problema:** Lo que requiero, es saber como puedo manejar los datos de esta forma y como eliminar una fila determinada del array, por ejemplo la del automóvil que puse arriba.

Espero darme a entender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Efectivamente los corchetes `[]` sirven para definir arrays mientras que las llaves `{}` son para crear objetos con propiedades.

Para tu caso lo más recomendable es crear un objeto coche al igual que lo harías con POO:

```
var coche = {"color": "rojo", "año": 2014}
```

Puedes aprender a usar objetos en JS aquí: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Te recomiendo que a la hora de pasar los datos por ajax utilices la función [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify) para convertirlo todo a JSON antes de enviar y estandarizar los datos.

En tu caso:

```js
var datos = ["Automovil", "Nissan", "2010", "Rojo"];

console.log(JSON.stringify(datos));

//devuelve: ["Automovil","Nissan","2010","Rojo"]
```

Puedes encontrar más info de como usar la función: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 1):

Para definir un array en javascript la sintaxis correcta es encerrar los elementos entre corchetes (`[...]`), no entre llaves.

Para eliminar un elemento de una posición determinada puedes utilizar el método `splice`, que recibe como argumentos el índice (con base 0) a partir del cual se desea eliminar elementos y el número de elementos a eliminar (en tu caso 1):

```js
// Definición del array
var datos = ["Automovil", "Nissan", "2010", "Rojo"];

console.log("Array inicial: ", datos);

// Eliminar elemento "Automovil" (índice 0)
datos.splice(0, 1);

console.log("Resultado: ", datos);
```

Answer (score 1):

Para trabajar con objetos e iterar por cada uno de ellos en un array, usas los objetos como elementos del array

```js
var data = [
   {
   nombre: 'Eduardo',
   age: 17,
   programming: { value: !false, desc: '1 año de experiencia'}
   }, 
   {
   nombre: 'Jacinta',
   age: 18,
   programming: { value: true, desc: '3 años de experiencia'}
   }
];

data.forEach(objActual => console.log('Personas: ' +objActual.nombre));

var filtered = data.filter(objActual => objActual.age >= 18); // Obtener personas mayores de edad.

console.log(`Hay ${filtered.length} personas mayores de edad.`);
```

Comment: Voy a checarlo. Entonces cada dato sería una fils o cada cada conjunto sería una sola fila?

Comment: Es un solo array, con el cual cada "fila" ( que es un objeto en javascript ) es un conjunto de datos en común, nombre, edad, etc

Answer (score 0):

Segun las respuestas que me han dado y la necesidad que tenia, pude llegar a una solución.

**SOLUCIÓN** 
La solución es combinar tanto los objetos `JSON` y los `Arrays` de Javascript.

```
var datos = {Automovil : [{Auto: [item1, item2, ...], Modelo: [item1, item2,..], Anio: [item1,item2,..]}]};
```

De esta manera podría usar:

```
datos.Automovil.Auto.push(item); //Agregar un nuevo Elemento
datos.Automovil.Auto.splice(0,1); //Eliminar según el indice
```